# (setq yas-snippet-dirs ...) not working

Tags: minor-mode, yasnippet

I am unable to set up yasnippet the way I want to set it up.

I only want to use yasnippet for a particular set of modes, so I don't want to use `yas-global-mode`.

I only want to use my own snippets, not the ones that come pre-packaged with the MELPA installation. I don't want it to ever load the MELPA snippets.

Unfortunately, the package is being insufferable; the only way I can figure out how to add my snippets and get them to actually work is to do the following:

```
(require 'yasnippet)

;; Use custom snippets.
(add-to-list 'yas-snippet-dirs "~/Dropbox/configs/emacs/snippets/")
(yas-reload-all)

(dolist (hook jrh-programming-modes)
  (add-hook hook 'yas-minor-mode))
```

I have to call `yas-reload-all`, or else my snippets aren't available. I have to use `add-to-list`, because for *some reason*, when I replace that line with `(setq yas-snippet-dirs '("~/Dropbox/configs/emacs/snippets/"))`, my snippets are not loaded. So I have to suffer through the loading of all the other snippets, which I never use.

What I would like to do is this:

```
;; Use custom snippets.
(setq yas-snippet-dirs '("~/Dropbox/configs/emacs/snippets/"))

(require 'yasnippet)

(dolist (hook jrh-programming-modes)
  (add-hook hook 'yas-minor-mode))
```

and never need to use the other snippets or reload at all. Of course, the above code does not work, even though in my head it seems like it should.

Any help on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take it up with https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/issues. `yasnippet` hasn't worked without `yas-global-mode` for ages.

Comment: How about the line of code in the enabling of `yas-minor-mode` that says:  `(dolist (mode (yas--modes-to-activate)) . . .`  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4):

From [yas-minor-mode does not load snippets](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/issues/544) (GitHub):

> I think when not using `yas-global-mode` you have to at least add a
>   `(yas-reload-all)` call somewhere to your `.emacs`. This will setup the
>   jit-loading tables (and not load actual snippets until `yas-minor-mode`
>   is activated in some buffer for which one of those tables has been
>   setup.
>
> It might be desirable to have this performed automatically, but I
>   think I've analysed this in the past and found it to not be suitable
>   (for some reason that I can't quite remember right now, sorry).
>
> Anyway, you have a workaround: add `(yas-reload-all)` somewhere in your
>   init file.

This is a bug; the solution I have discovered is the maintainer's recommended workaround in the interim.